# After migrating from WAMP to MAMP I get the ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: wordpress, migration, wamp, mamp

I am a Wordpress beginner and for training purposes I created two websites in my Windows PC by using WAMP.  Recently I changed my laptop for a Mac and I tried to export the two websites into my new Mac/MAMP by using phpMyAdmin.
After having sorted out few issues due to the root password and the MAMP 8888 Apache port, I succeeded to have one website fully working but unfortunately I am not able to make the second one up and running. When I try to open the website from Chrome I get a:

"The localhost page isn’t working - localhost didn’t send any data. - ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" message;

and if I look at the MAMP Apache_error.log I see the following messages:

[Thu Dec 15 23:28:42 2016] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/.DS_Store, referer: http://localhost:8888/MAMP/?language=English

[Thu Dec 15 23:30:19 2016] [notice] child pid 13889 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

[Thu Dec 15 23:30:19 2016] [notice] child pid 13886 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

[Thu Dec 15 23:30:24 2016] [notice] child pid 13888 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

[Thu Dec 15 23:30:26 2016] [notice] child pid 13885 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

[Thu Dec 15 23:30:27 2016] [notice] child pid 13457 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

[Thu Dec 15 23:30:58 2016] [notice] child pid 12946 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

[Thu Dec 15 23:31:58 2016] [notice] child pid 12671 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

I tried also to re-export the database of the not-working website few times and I have also tried to move the website folder in the Mac into a different directory (note: now both websites are into MAMP/htdocs) but the behaviour has not changed: one website works fine while the other shows the error above.

I am running out of ideas and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Fabz

Answer (score 1):

Just let you know I have found the cause of the issue. It looks like there is an incompatibility with the BeaverBuilder lite plugin. As soon as I have deleted its folder I managed to access the website.
I have raised the issue to BeaverBuilder.

Fabz